Difference between using / or not in react with react-router-dom
So, I'm working on a project where I'm using react router dom in order to create a centralized application for the reception of documents.
I noted that there's a difference when I try to use the react router like this:
<NavLink to='something'>
That when I use it like this:
<NavLink to='/something'>
The route for the first one changes like this:
http://localhost:3000/parentPage/something
The route for the second one changes like this:
http://localhost:3000/something.
Is there any way for me to dynamically renderize different content if I want to use the first one in order to indicate that the link I'm using belongs to a Parent without creating new pages for every route and without declaring the links on the App.js?
Thanks in advance!
enter image description here
I'm expecting to have content renderized dynamically in this URL
